# what the mening of (+) in BETWEEN function

Tags: sql, join, plsql, left-join

Recently I observed the following syntax:

```
AND TRUNC (SYSDATE) + 1 BETWEEN a(+) AND b(+)
```

I know that the (+) sign is used to address left or right join in conditions like:

```
and a = b(+)
```

... but I have no idea what it means in the **BETWEEN** function.

Can someone explain, please, or better give an example using **BETWEEN** function?

Thank you,

Comment: It means that you are using archaic outer join syntax.  Switch to proper, explicit `outer join` syntax.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: I know it is an archaic outer join syntax but how it works in BETWEEN function?

Comment: @i3rutt: "a" or "b" are not functions. in my example, they are columns in tables

Comment: see other question/answer.. in your case it implies that columns A and B are on the outer table and thus could be null.  `x BETWEEN NULL and NULL` I believe will be false

Comment: It means the same thing in a `between` expression as it does with `=`. Presumably `a` and `b` are columns in an outer-joined table, and the query needs to avoid excluding rows from the driving table where no corresponding row exists in the outer-joined table.

Answer (score 0):

The [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries006.htm#sthref3178) says:

> Oracle recommends that you use the FROM clause OUTER JOIN syntax
>   rather than the Oracle join operator. Outer join queries that use the
>   Oracle join operator (+) are subject to the following rules and
>   restrictions, which do not apply to the FROM clause OUTER JOIN syntax: